# Why does $\displaystyle \frac{1}{100} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$ represent the worm on the rubber band ratio?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Applications)'s the description from Wikipedia:

> Suppose that a worm crawls
> along an infinitely-elastic one-meter rubber band at the same time as
> the rubber band is uniformly stretched. If the worm travels 1
> centimeter per minute and the band stretches 1 meter per minute, will
> the worm ever reach the end of the rubber band? The answer,
> counterintuitively, is "yes", for after n minutes, the ratio of the
> distance travelled by the worm to the total length of the rubber band
> is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{100} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$.

Now my problem is that for say $n=2$ we get $\frac{1}{100}(1+\frac{1}{2})=\frac{3}{200}$. But since only two minutes passed the worm could only have traveled 2 centimeters while the band was stretched to 2 meters giving a ratio of $\frac{2}{200}$. Therefore there must be an error with my reasoning (or on Wikipedia), where is it?

Comment: The stretching of the rubber band contributes to the worm's speed. For instance, a worm at the far end of the band would be travelling at 1.01 meters per minute. (The question is partly to blame here: it should really say something like "the worm _crawls_ at one centimeter per minute.")

Comment: hmm... I am still not sure if I understood. Say $n=1$, with the above formula we would get $1/100$. But by the phrasing of the question the worm travels 1cm per minute and the band is stretched by 1 meter per minute. So if the worm traveled 1cm, then one minute must have passed and the band should have been stretched as well to 2 meters, giving $1/200$, no?

Comment: Basically I do not understand how the stretching affects the worm's speed. If after 1 minute the worm is at 1/100 then it would make sense for me that the stretching was applied after the worm moved, since it would just stretch the worms position 1/100 to 2/200=1/100. But if the stretching was applied continuously during the whole minute while the worm is moving then the stretching effect on the worm's position should be smaller, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia article add, immediately after the text you cite, "In fact the actual ratio is a little less than this sum as the band expands continuously".
They are approximating the process as a staggered, discrete march:

1. worm moves
2. band stretch
3. goto 1)

First minute, 1cm over 1 m, and the term is $\frac{1}{100}$, second minute, 1 cm over 2 m,  $\frac{1}{200}$, these are the increments to be added.
Your $\frac{2}{200}$ refers to total forward movement over actual length after 2 mind, which is a different topic.

Comment: Clarifying, thanks! I think you meant after the first minute the term is $1/100$, right? So this term is higher than the actual ratio, because this term assumes that the stretching is done after the worm moved?

Comment: corrected, and yes, that is what I believe (and the comment in the article confirms they do not look at as a continuously deforming band)

Answer (score 0):

If you crawl 1 cm while the rubber has length $k$ meters (i.e., for simplicity we assume that worm crawls at the beginning of ecvery full second and the band stretches in-between), you improve your ratio by $\frac1{100k}$. Adding the first $n$ "improvements" gives the result.